# Limitations of SQL Views-Order by Clause not supported

Tags: sql-server

why can't we use Order By clause while creating the view. What is the reason behind SQL supporting Order by clause with TOP clause mentioned in the query and not supporting the same without TOP clause

Answer (score 1):

A view is nothing but a virtual table and the order in which data is stored in a table can never be guaranteed in any RDBMS.

What you will need to do is:

```
SELECT <Column1>,<Column2>,....,<ColumnN>
FROM <MyView>
ORDER BY <MyColumn>
```

Comment: SELECT <Column1>,<Column2>,....,<ColumnN>
FROM <MyView>
ORDER BY <MyColumn>
this is sorting the result explicitly..
Why can't we sort it while creating the view itself?

Answer (score 0):

Because the tsql is relational and view is a relation and the relation doesn't have order.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL, a `view` is a virtual table based on the result-set of an SQL statement. A view contains rows and columns, just like a real table. The fields in a `view` are fields from one or more `real tables` in the database.

You can add SQL functions, WHERE, and JOIN statements to a view and present the data as if the data were coming from one single table.

For ordering the resulted data you need to query it and apply order by clause as per your requirement.